# how can I fit two lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want to fit these two lists with sklearn but at the end it say : could not convert string to float... can you help me with that?

```
 from sklearn import tree
 x = ['BMW', '20000miles', '2010']
 y = ['12000']
 clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
 clf = clf.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: I would suggest reading some beginner articles on data prep for machine learning.  Surely they will cover the feature encoding

Answer (score 0):

A number of things.
From the documentation:

```
X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
The training input samples. Internally, it will be converted to dtype=np.float32 and if a sparse matrix is provided to a sparse csc_matrix.

yarray-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
The target values (class labels) as integers or strings.
```

Your input to fit should be an array of shape (n_samples, n_features). Do you have 1 sample with 3 features? I suppose that is ok, but fitting 1 sample doesn't make much sense.

But your model can't interpret "BMW", it expects a float. So if you have 3 types of cars, BMW, AUDI, MERCEDES, convert them to a number, i.e. 1,2,3 to represent them.

Comment: No its about 6000 cars

Comment: Look at what Chris said, and read the documentation on the sklearn model. You have to prepare the data in a way that the model can handle it. A lot of times this means converting things to numbers. Have a value for the manufacturer, remove miles from the second item, etc